# bug in chrome.storage.local that seems to affect extensions only on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to set, and later request the data stored locally in an extension

The way I am doing this is sending a request from the content script as follows

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "fetchData"}, doSomething)
```

On the background page, the message is received and parsed by:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(getData);
```

where getData is a function as follows:

```
var getData = function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.method == "fetchData"){
        chrome.storage.local.get('myinfo',function(items){
            console.log(items);
            if (items.myinfo){
                sendResponse({status: items.myinfo});
            } else {
                sendResponse({status: items.myinfo});
            }
        }); //storage.local.get
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now the first time this is run, storage is empty, so items is an empty object {}

Therefore, items.myinfo is undefined

This is indeed the case when I test on my chrome installation on Linux.

However, when running the extension on chrome on a Mac ( OS X 10.9.2 header below)...

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36 module=default version=1
```

...the background page spits up the following error:

```
Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'myinfo' of undefined
```

It turns out that in this instance items is undefined, not an empty object.

I am trying to figure out if checking for an undefined items, and then populating chrome.storage.local with some data...

```
storage.set({'myinfo': message.key}, function() {
    });
```

... helps resolve the issue, or if it continues to persist.

Why is this behavior of chrome.local.storage.get different on different OS's. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Could you change `console.log(items);` to `console.log(items, chrome.runtime.lastError);` and post the error message you get?

Comment: I meant on the same browser. `items` is only `undefined` when an error has occurred.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was prematurely published. We haven't been able to replicate that on the same version of Chrome on a different computer (running Max OS X 10.9.2) 

The above error messages were sent to us the user of an extension after reporting a bug. We have requested the user to report the error message after this addition

Comment: As for why it's different on different platforms, C++ is not a write once run anywhere platform. So the developers essentially have to write rendering code for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS, as well as any other platforms they support. So someone likely didn't follow the spec somewhere and this is a bug... you should file an issue in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: Facing the same issue on latest chrome (55.0.2883.95) on mac, did you guys find some solution?