# Error in response to storage.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, google-chrome

I'm not sure why I have this error. Everything seems to be running fine and I don't have the error in Safari but when I open Chrome, it seems to not be happy.
[image]

Some context; I am running node and doing some single page d3 dabblings. I'm not developing any chrome extensions so I'm confused where this is coming from.

[Similar but didn't help SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405121/bug-in-chrome-storage-local-that-seems-to-affect-extensions-only-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: If you go to your Chrome Settings, then click the Extensions tab, then click the Developer Mode checkbox at the top, it will show you the ID strings for each extension. If you find the extension that has the ID (that long string that starts with "djcfkadj..."), it might give you a clue.

Comment: I found that it was from 'Reaction Packs for Facebook' but why would that not play nice with what I was developing? I didn't see that error on other pages, like Google.com

Comment: I'd guess it's a bug in the extension. Do you have the latest version? It looks like it was just updated last Tuesday.

Comment: I had v1.0.5 I think. Oh well